# Plotly.js - delete a trace shows an error

Tags: plotly

I am using Plotly.js library for charting. At some point I need to delete some traces from the chart. The command is simple:

```
Plotly.deleteTraces(div_chart, traceIndex);
```

That generates an error:

```
TypeError: t.match is not a function
at r.cleanId (plotly-latest.min.js:7)
at Object.r.cleanData (plotly-latest.min.js:7)
at Object.r.redraw (plotly-latest.min.js:7)
at Object.t [as deleteTraces] (plotly-latest.min.js:7)
```

but deletes the trace anyway. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Update.
I think this is what causes the problem. I am using area charts with fill: 'tozeroy' for a trace.  without it doesn't crash although it is a critical part of the product.

Comment: Do you call a match() function somewhere?

Comment: No, I dont think so.